# surge.sh does not allow modifying robots.txt

Tags: surge.sh

The default robots.txt file disable search engine indexing? And I cannot replace it with my own. What did I miss?

That's the default and fixed one:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 3):

According to slack, robots.txt files on *.surge.sh subdomains are locked to prevent link farming... sad.